# How do I generate a list of js scripts to include in my HTML page based on my Typescript project (compiled into multiple js files)

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6

I have a project with a large amount of ts files. At the moment we compile all of these into one js file and just load that one js file in our HTML. This file is guaranteed to have all the source in the correct order (if we have our references correct anyway) and means we only have to make 1 request over the wire.

To ease development I am considering changing our compile method to compile each TS file to a single js file. This will make compilation essentially instant and will make coverage reports better for example and will allow for file watchers to instantly run tests and so on. For the released version we would still use the single compiled js file though.

The major pain point with this approach though is maintaining the list of js files to be loaded into our HTML page and making sure that they are in the correct order. Is there a way of generating this list automatically?

Thanks

Comment: Why do these processes conflict? Could you create a workflow that is TS -> ES (with typescript compiler doing individual files -> bundled single file and have the tests  operate off of the individual files? The per-file watches would be triggered and the app would still use the single file output. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: the bundled single file would still require a compile step. We work in Visual Studio and it can compile each ts file to a js file on save. Currently though we need to a build before we can actually test it.

Comment: Could you include bundle watchers that act on JS file updates?

Comment: I can't see how that would help...

Comment: It avoids the issue by triggering the build on save as well.

Comment: Though if that's not quite ideal, how about a dynamic module loader that can understand the require() statements generated by TS? That way you'll only need to include the loader configuration and the base file. The rest can be loaded as needed.